# Sending specials characters to the serial display from the arduino uno

Tags: arduino, character, symbols

I want to know if the Uno can send special symbols like of a sun or of an umbrella, via serial, to the display of my laptop.  For example, at: http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/search.htm?q=rain&preview=entity, it shows an umbrella, entitled "weather, rainy", with character code: U+2602.  I found out that the Uno can send the degree symbol for temperature with this: Serial.print(char(176));  Is there someway that it can also send the umbrella or other specials symbols?
Thank you,
Steve

Comment: It depends on what you are using to receive the data and display it on your laptop. A Unicode sequence is jus a sequence of bytes. The Arduino can send any sequence if bytes you like on the serial port. It is up to the receiving program on your laptop to decide if it is a Unicode character and what to do with it.

Comment: I upload my program to the Uno, using arduino.exe.  Uno starts to work.  Then, I open up the serial monitor in arduino.exe, where I see whatever output the Uno sends back. Can you give me an example using Serial.print(char()); showing how the Uno can send back a unicode code like U+2602, so that I can see it in the serial monitor?  Thank you very much.

Comment: Ok, now I understand. I don't think the serial monitor supports Unicode so you can't display Unicode there.

Comment: Do you think this might work?  http://www.forward.com.au/pfod/ArduinoProgramming/Languages/index.html.

Comment: That can help if you want to put the unicode into a string literal in your sketch, but it won't display in the serial monitor because it doesn't support unicode.  You need some other application on your PC to receive the data that can display unicode

Comment: How would I put U+2602 into a string literal and then use it in a: Serial.print(char());  There's also this: code.google.com/p/arduino/issues/detail?id=119 but I am not sure how to add it to the arduino IDE.  But the comment: "\x, which can be used to send raw bytes" seemed promising.  And I am looking to using other serial monitors such as Putty, to see if they would work.

Comment: The Arudino side is simply a matter of sending the bytes.  You need a different terminal program on the PC side